# How to fix "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error with a function that needs to loop 1 million times

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a coding challenge where I need to first create a function that shows how many iterations of the Collatz conjecture it takes to get to 1, and then find the largest number of iterations for a number within 1 million. 
This is the challenge: https://projecteuler.net/problem=14
And here's the code:

```
// Collatz Conjecture
function collatz(n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        throw "the number needs to be greater than 1";
    }
    for(var i = 0; n != 1; i++) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n /= 2;
        } else {
            n = (n * 3) + 1;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

// Greatest Collatz Within 1,000,000

function largestCollatz() {
  var arr = [];
 for(var i = 2; i <= 1000000; i++) {
     arr.push(collatz(i));
    }
    return Math.max(...arr);
}
```

The collatz() function works as expected, but when I try to use largestCollatz(), it throws "Maximum call stack size reached.". I tried changing the 1 million to only a hundred thousand, and it works, but that doesn't satisfy the conditions of the challenge.

Comment: The problem is here: `Math.max(...arr)`. You can trivially replace that with your own implementation (hint: inside the loop, instead of `arr.push` just check if `collatz(i)` is greater than the current max value)

Comment: As a side note, `collatz()` should use memoization and not recompute already computed `n`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your calculating logic. The issue is with calling Math.max  with a million parameters. You can easily loop this yourself, or better yet, don't create such an array in the first place. I'd store in a variable the highest value you encounter with each iteration so by the time the loop finishes, you already know the highest number of operations. I'd also maintain a second variable to keep track of the starting number so you know the number you started with and know the number of operations associated with it. Maintaining a massive array is a waste of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spreading into `Math.max`, you can call `Math.max` on every iteration instead:

```js
// Collatz Conjecture
function collatz(n) {
  if (n <= 1) {
    throw "the number needs to be greater than 1";
  }
  for (var i = 0; n != 1; i++) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
      n /= 2;
    } else {
      n = (n * 3) + 1;
    }
  }
  return i;
}

// Greatest Collatz Within 1,000,000

function largestCollatz() {
  var arr = [];
  let maxSoFar = 0;
  for (var i = 2; i <= 1000000; i++) {
    maxSoFar = Math.max(maxSoFar, collatz(i));
  }
  return maxSoFar;
}

console.log(largestCollatz());
```

If you wanted to increase the performance of the code, you could create a lookup table for the number of iterations required for each number, and use that lookup table instead of brute force when possible.

```js
const map = new Map();
function collatz(n) {
  if (n <= 1) {
    throw "the number needs to be greater than 1";
  }
  if (map.has(n)) {
    return map.get(n);
  }
  const next = n % 2 === 0 ? n / 2 : (n * 3) + 1;
  if (next === 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  const result = 1 + collatz(next);
  map.set(n, result);
  return result;
}

// Greatest Collatz Within 1,000,000

function largestCollatz() {
  var arr = [];
  let maxSoFar = 0;
  for (var i = 2; i <= 1000000; i++) {
    maxSoFar = Math.max(maxSoFar, collatz(i));
  }
  return maxSoFar;
}

console.log(largestCollatz());
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you use brute force algorithm that is inefficient.this is my solution to problem 14 from project Euler. it takes a few second to run. the key is you should save previous results in a dictionary so you don't have to compute those results again.:

```
#problem 14 project euler
import time
start=time.time()
has2={}
def collatz(x):
    seq=[]
    seq.append(x)
    temp=x
    while(temp>1):
        if temp%2==0:
            temp=int(temp/2)
            if temp in has2:
                seq+=has2[temp]
                break
            else:
                seq.append(temp)
        else:
            temp=3*temp+1
            if temp in has2:
                seq+=has2[temp]
                break
            else:
                seq.append(temp)


    has2[x]=seq            
    return len(seq)

num=0
greatest=0
for i in range(1000000):
    c=collatz(i)
    if num<c:
        num=c
        greatest=i
print('{0} has {1} elements. calculation time ={2} seconds.'.format(greatest,num,time.time()-start))
```